ERROR: (gcloud.compute.instances.start) HTTPError 400: The instance resource "VM" is already being used by "snapshot"
I have an automated procedure that uses some google cloud VMs that are already created. I do not manage the cloud environment directly as this is managed by the cloud team. I recently had this error. upon using gcloud command to start some VMs. I get this error:
ERROR: (gcloud.compute.instances.start) HTTPError 400: The instance resource 'projects/<my_project>/zones/us-central1-f/instances/<vm_name>' is already being used by 'projects/<my_project>/global/snapshots/<snapshot_name>'
I am trying to understand what is going on as a concept. Regardless of my being able to ask the cloud team for clarification. I have a personal lab environment where I have tried starting a VM while the process of taking a snapshot is running. the machine runs normally. I am assuming there is some type of automated snapshot that would prevent the machine from starting up at that time?
